# Nuxt3 / Netlify - Form not sending data (no errors)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, netlify, nuxtjs3

I’ve seen a lot of questions regarding this online, but I can’t find a solution that works.

I’m trying to get form submission to work with a Nuxt 3 app. I have added everything necessary (from Netlify doc and internet searches) in the form for it to work but nothing.

I get no errors in console or network, no issue at all, but no email in Netlify either.

Here's the site https://pixelvisionagency.com/contact in case anyboby wants to try it

**Form html:**

```
<form class="form mb-6" name="contact" method="post" action="/thanks" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
    <p hidden>
        <label>Don’t fill this out: <input name="bot-field" /></label>
    </p>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="checkboxes clearfix">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="website" /><span>Website</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" value="app" /><span>App</span> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" value="logo" /><span>Logo</span> </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field mt-6">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-half">
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label label--normal" for="input1">{{ $t('contact.form.name_label') }}</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" :placeholder="$t('contact.form.name_placeholder')"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-half">
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label label--normal" for="input2">{{ $t('contact.form.email_label') }}</label>
                    <input class="input" type="email" id="input2" name="input2" :placeholder="$t('contact.form.email_placeholder')"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field mt-6">
        <label class="label label--normal" for="textarea">{{ $t('contact.form.details_label') }}</label>
        <div class="control">
            <textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" name="textarea" :placeholder="$t('contact.form.details_placeholder')"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button form__button" type="submit">
                {{ $t('contact.form.button') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```